# CATIA.StartCommand "Edit" not workng

Tags: vba, catia

```vb
Sub Assypublication()
    Dim productDocument1 As ProductDocument
    Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

    Dim selection1 As Selection
    Set selection1 = productDocument1.Selection

    selection1.Search "(Name=*NHD* & CATAsmSearch.Product),all"

    CATIA.StartCommand "Edit"
end sub
```

why this command is not working ?

I am trying to to activate filtered object in CATIA vb

but [ CATIA.StartCommand "Edit"] is not working

Comment: Do you get an error? What do you want to achieve?